# how to add onClickListener in each ArrayList's TableRow

Tags: android, tablerow

My tablesRows just doesn't seems to have the onClickListener set.
I am adding them dynamically to a tableLayout,i am storing them into a ArrayList
and i want to set every tablerow onClickListener.

```
 for(TableRow i : trs)
    i.setOnClickListener(this);
```

trs is a ArrayList.

Nothing happens, onClick isn't called.(i put Log to see)

What's Wrong?
Are there another way of put onClickListener in tablerows that are inside a arraylist?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to illustrate your problem.

Comment: A lot could be wrong, but it's impossible to tell without seeing more code. For example: if the Views inside the table rows have their own input listeners (onClick, onTouch, etc) then the row's listener is never called... or your listener could work just fine, but have a logic flaw in  it...